# Таг form из Spring выдает исключение

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

```
<%@ taglib prefix="springform" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="core" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<core:url value="/resources/static/auth/start.css"/>">
    <script src="<core:url value='/resources/libs/jquery_3.1.0.js'/>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(":button").click(function () {
                $(this).addClass("clicked");
                var input = $(".department_adder");
                $(".department_adder").append("<springform:option value="dep">" + input.val() + '</springform:option>');
                setTimeout(unselect, 200);
                input.val('');
            });
        });
        function unselect() {
            $(":button").removeClass("clicked");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="reg_container reg_org_container">
    <springform:form method="post" modelAttribute="organization">
    <div class="reg_block">
        <label>
            название организации:
            <springform:input path="name" type="text"/>
            <springform:errors path="name" cssClass="error"/>
            <img src="../../resources/checkbox.jpg">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="reg_block">
        <label>
            описание:
            <springform:textarea path="description"></springform:textarea>
            <springform:errors path="description" cssClass="error"/>
            <img src="../../resources/checkbox.jpg">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="reg_block">
        <label>
            отделы / структурные подразделения:
            <springform:select path="departments" name="departments" class="department_adder">
                <springform:option value="dep">Без названия</springform:option>
            </springform:select>
            <button type="button">добавить</button>
        </label>

    </div>
    <div class="reg_block">
        <input type="submit" class="auth_submit_button" value="Зарегистрировать">
    </div>
    </springform:form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

При попытке использовать элемент `<springform:select` ("http://www.springframework.org/tags/form") выпадает исключение:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The 'option' tag can only be used inside a valid 'select' tag.
    at org.springframework.web.util.TagUtils.assertHasAncestorOfType(TagUtils.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionTag.assertUnderSelectTag(OptionTag.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionTag.onWriteTagContent(OptionTag.java:309)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementBodyTag.writeTagContent(AbstractHtmlElementBodyTag.java:45)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:83)
    at org.apache.jsp.views.auth.neworg_jsp._jspService(neworg_jsp.java:171)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:591)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:527)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:894)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:673)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.JspRequest.doInclude(JspRequest.java:123)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractViewRequest.dispatch(AbstractViewRequest.java:47)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.render.ChainedDelegateRenderer.render(ChainedDelegateRenderer.java:68)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:188)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.execute(InsertAttributeModel.java:132)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:299)
    at org.apache.jsp.views.auth.base_005fauth_005freg_jsp._jspx_meth_t_005finsertAttribute_005f0(base_005fauth_005freg_jsp.java:193)
    at org.apache.jsp.views.auth.base_005fauth_005freg_jsp._jspService(base_005fauth_005freg_jsp.java:134)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:265)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.doForward(ServletRequest.java:228)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractClientRequest.dispatch(AbstractClientRequest.java:57)
    at org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:397)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:238)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.render(DefinitionRenderer.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:146)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:314)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Не могу понять что в нем невалидного. Из исходников понял, что возникает исключение из-за того, что у тага option отсутствует родитель. Что я упустил?

Comment: По-моему он ругается на `springform:option` в коде на JavaScript. Попробуйте использовать там обычный `option` и не используйте один и тот же вид кавычек вокруг литерала и внутри него.

Comment: Вы правы. js ведь уже с отрендеренной разметкой работает. не дошло. спасибо

Comment: Не хотелось бы сотдавать отдельный вопрос. Может быть кто подскажет, select ведь просто отображет список? Мне нужно чтобы значения можно было добавлять. Я вначале хотел использовать <input  list=""  с <datalist> Но аналога в спринге вроде нет. Как создать изменяемый список, чтобы затем отправлять его на сервер?

Comment: О, боги! Я даже не обратил внимания на наличие в js-коде jsp-разметки.

Answer (score 3):

У него не может быть атрибута `name`, а атрибут `class` следует писать как `cssClass`.

Comment: не помогло. такой же стэктрейс

Answer (score 2):

Мой ответ из обсуждения выше, оказавшийся правильным:

> По-моему он ругается на springform:option в коде на JavaScript.
>   Попробуйте использовать там обычный option и не используйте один и тот
>   же вид кавычек вокруг литерала и внутри него.